# Decode utf8 entities from json into utf8 C++

Tags: c++, json, c++11, utf-8

I have a string with utf8 entities (I'm not sure I named it right):

```
std::string std = "\u0418\u043d\u0434\u0435\u043a\u0441";
```

How could I convert it into something more readable? I use g++ with C++11 support, but after couple of hours digging in std::codecvt manual I get no result:

```
std::string std = "\u0418\u043d\u0434\u0435\u043a\u0441";

wstring_convert<codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>,char16_t> convert; 
string dest = convert.to_bytes(std);
```

returns nightmare stacktrace started with:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>, char16_t>::to_bytes(std::string&)
```

I hope there is another way.

Answer (score 4):

First off, your use of `std::wstring_convert` is backwards.  You have a UTF-8 encoded `std::string` that you want to convert to a wide Unicode string.  You are getting the compiler error because `to_bytes()` does not take a `std::string` as input.  It takes a `std::wstring_convert::wide_string` as input (which is `std::u16string` in your case, due to your use of `char16_t` in the specialization), so you need to use `from_bytes()` instead of `to_bytes()`:

```
std::string std = "\u0418\u043d\u0434\u0435\u043a\u0441";

std::wstring_convert<codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>, char16_t> convert; 
std::u16string dest = convert.from_bytes(std);
```

Now, that being said, Section 9 of the [JSON specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) states:

> 9 String
>
> A string is a sequence of Unicode code points wrapped with quotation marks (U+0022). All characters may be placed within the quotation marks except for the characters that must be escaped: quotation mark (U+0022), reverse solidus (U+005C), and the control characters U+0000 to U+001F. There are two-character escape sequence representations of some characters.
>
> `\"` represents the quotation mark character (U+0022).
>
> `\\` represents the reverse solidus character (U+005C).
>
> `\/` represents the solidus character (U+002F).
>
> `\b` represents the backspace character (U+0008).
>
> `\f` represents the form feed character (U+000C).
>
> `\n` represents the line feed character (U+000A).
>
> `\r` represents the carriage return character (U+000D).
>
> `\t` represents the character tabulation character (U+0009).
>
> So, for example, a string containing only a single reverse solidus character may be represented as "`\\`".
>
> **Any code point may be represented as a hexadecimal number**. The meaning of such a number is determined by ISO/IEC 10646. **If the code point is in the Basic Multilingual Plane (U+0000 through U+FFFF), then it may be represented as a six-character sequence: a reverse solidus, followed by the lowercase letter `u`, followed by four hexadecimal digits that encode the code point**. Hexadecimal digits can be digits (U+0030 through U+0039) or the hexadecimal letters `A` through `F` in uppercase (U+0041 through U+0046) or lowercase (U+0061 through U+0066). So, for example, a string containing only a single reverse solidus character may be represented as "`\u005C`".
>
> The following four cases all produce the same result:
>
> "`\u002F`"
>
> "`\u002f`"
>
> "`\/`"
>
> "`/`"
>
> **To escape a code point that is not in the Basic Multilingual Plane, the character is represented as a twelve-character sequence, encoding the UTF-16 surrogate pair**. So for example, a string containing only the G clef character (U+1D11E) may be represented as "`\uD834\uDD1E`".

The raw JSON data itself may be encoded in UTF-8 (the most common encoding), UTF-16, etc.  But regardless of the encoding used, the character sequence `"\u0418\u043d\u0434\u0435\u043a\u0441"` represents the UTF-16 codeunit sequence `U+0418 U+043d U+0434 U+0435 U+043a U+0441`, which is the Unicode character string `"Индекс"`.

If you use an actual JSON parser (such as [JSON for Modern C++](https://github.com/nlohmann/json), [jsoncpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp), [RapidJSON](http://rapidjson.org), etc), it will parse the UTF-16 codeunit values for you and return readable Unicode strings.

But, if you are processing the JSON data manually, then you will have to manually decode any `\x` and `\uXXXX` escape sequences.  `std::wstring_convert` cannot do that for you.  It can only convert the JSON from `std::string` to `std::wstring`/`std:::u16string`, if that makes it easier for you to parse the data.  However, you still have to parse the *content* of the JSON separately.

Afterwards, if so desired, you can use `std::wstring_convert` to convert any extracted `std::wstring`/`std::u16string` strings back to UTF-8 to save memory.

Comment: I would be happy to use JSON for Modern C++, but when I try to parse json with it I got an error: what():  parse error - unexpected '�' . The code is just: auto j3 = json::parse(json_string);

Comment: `�` is Unicode codepoint `U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER` (UTF-8 byte sequence `0xEF 0xBF 0xBD`). Your JSON data likely went through a charset conversion using the wrong charset before it was then passed to the JSON parser. The "JSON for Modern C++" parser accepts only valid UTF-8 input.

Answer (score 0):

What you see are not entities but code points. You are defining characters via  Unicode escape sequences and the compiler automatically converts them to UTF-8. A typical way to convert that to UTF-16 and vice versa is this:

```
static std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter;
std::string ws2s(const std::wstring &wstr) {
  std::string narrow = converter.to_bytes(wstr);
  return narrow;
}

std::wstring s2ws(const std::string &str) {
  std::wstring wide = converter.from_bytes(str);
  return wide;
}
```

Of course you cannot convert the original string into another string of the same type (std::string) as it cannot hold such characters. This is why the UTF-16 code was converted to UTF-8 by your compiler in the first place.

Comment: I'm pretty sure those functions have zero clue about the `\u` notation.

Comment: They don't need to. The compiler will do that, because it can handle Unicode sequences in strings. If the OP wanted to keep the original Unicode escape sequences in the string he would have used '\\u0418' etc. (and my answer would be different).